# Best product setup in Magento 1

Tags: configurable-product, configuration, configurable-swatches

Alright guys, I need some help to make sure this is the best way to do this.  We have a client selling furniture.  Let's say we have the following example data set:

1. sofa
2. love seat

Then we have 3 fabrics

1. red
2. blue
3. Gold

The sofa is $100 in any color, but gold.  Gold is +$10

The love seat is $90 in any color, but gold.  Gold is +$5

How should we setup our products?

Right now we are doing this:

Sofa - a Configurable with below simples:
Sofa BLUE
Sofa RED
Sofa Gold (+10 on the associated tab.)

Love Seat - a Configurable with below simples:
Love Seat BLUE
Love Seat RED
Love Seat Gold (+5 on the associated tab.)

What is happening is I fear we will eventually run into some scalability issues.  Because while I gave 2 products and 3 fabric examples here - the real test case is slightly over 1,000 products and 100 fabrics.

Is this the best way considering that fabrics have varying prices based on which configurable they are attached to?  If it's also important to know, we are using magento swatching as well to show the fabric swatch as a tile next to the add to cart button.

Thanks

Comment: The only solution I can think of is cofigurable product, what exactly is your question.

Comment: I guess the questions is "Is this the best solution or does anyone have any other better solution?"  Sounds like you agree with my setup that it is correct.  Which makes me feel good that I have not missed anything.